# Script para identificar 2 serviços ativos, derrubar os 2 e subir apenas 1

Tags: windows, script, batch, microsoft, vbscript

Seguinte, tenho um serviço aqui em meu ambiente que roda em algumas máquinas, porém este serviço não pode ficar duplicado ( não podem ter 2 serviços ativos ao mesmo tempo ) gostaria de saber se é possível redigir um script que verifique se tem 2 serviços ativos ou mais, desative os 2 ou mais e ative somente 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> em *RtlService*, altere para o nome do serviço desejado.
>   O script entrará em loop, e sempre que houver mais de 1 deste serviço
>    ele irá finalizar todos desse tipo, e irá iniciar novamente o serviço.

```
@echo off
mode 100,2
:loop
cls

set servico=RtlService

if not exist %tmp%\servdupl (md %tmp%\servdupl)

cd %tmp%\servdupl

tasklist | find /i "services" | find /i "%servico%">servdupl.txt

type "servdupl.txt" | find /v /c "">num.txt

set /p num=<num.txt

if "%num%" gtr "1" (net stop %servico%

net start %servico%
goto loop)
```

Comment: Dica: caso queira saber o nome correto do serviço,
digite NET START no prompt e verá a lista com os serviços que foram iniciados no Windows!
(Testado no Windows 7)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Cristian, este escript é pra ser salvo como VBS ? OBS : estou usando windows10

Comment: como .cmd ou .bat