# Script para verificar processo em execução e finalizar ou não

Tags: windows, script, bash, cmd, batch

eu tenho um processo chamado monitor.exe e o mesmo não pode ter 2 processos ativos por se tratar de um monitor de impressão que caso tenha 2 processos ativos o mesmo irá emitir 2 notas fiscais duplicadas, entao, gostaria de saber se tem como eu fazer um script que verifica se o processo está ativo, se tem somente 1 ativo e caso tenha mais de 1 finalize e deixe somente 1 ativo ?

tentei fazer um script simples com taskkill /F /IM monitor.exe e depois executar um start \caminho do .exe\

porém as vezes quando eu finalizo o processo ele sobe sozinho ai se eu der o start ficam os 2 duplicados novamente, alguem tem alguma ideia ?

Comment: Esse "monitor.exe", você que desenvolveou? Em qual linguagem é feito esse monitor? Talvez validação deveria ser dentro do próprio sistema.

Comment: o sistema nao é meu, é terceirizado, por isso estou tendo que fazer esse script pq eu nao tenho acesso ao codigo da aplicação

Comment: bash é uma tag relevante aqui?

Comment: é relevante pois existe um bash para windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O comando `wmic process where name="monitor.exe" | find "monitor.exe" /c` retorna a quantidade de processos do arquivo `monitor.exe` em execução.

Para poder fazer uma verificação da quantidade de processos em execução podemos salvar o resultado desse comando na variável `%pcount%` com o script abaixo:

```
@echo off

set pname=monitor.exe

set pcommand="wmic process where name="%pname%" | find "%pname%" /c"

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN (' %pcommand% ') DO SET pcount=%%i

if %pcount% GTR 1 (
    echo Tem mais de um processo.
    taskkill /f /im %pname%
    start pasta\para\%pname%

) else (
    echo Tem um ou nenhum processo.
)
pause
```

Comment: pergunta duplicada ... você já fez essa pergunta aqui e eu já respondi ela.

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/291737/script-para-identificar-2-serviços-ativos-derrubar-os-2-e-subir-apenas-1

Comment: cristian, na vdd uma é para um serviço a outra é para um processo

Comment: apenas edite o script, o processo é o mesmo para processos